# use relative path in jQuery load

Tags: jquery, path, load, relative-path

I have a .load jquery running in a file which I am accessing from this url

```
http://example.com/site_folder/case-studies/firstcase
```

Now the file has been saved under this directory

```
site_folder (dir)
     assets (dir)
        case_study_content (dir)
             file.txt (file)
```

My code is

```
$( "#slider li#"+nextId ).load( "../assets/case_study_content/file.txt #pickup");
```

it doesn't load the file content.

Now if I keep the file under site_folder and do the load as

```
 $( "#slider li#"+nextId ).load( "file.txt #pickup");
```

it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a relative path, it's irrelevant where you loaded the script from. The path is relative to the page that loaded the script.

If your page is inside the `site_folder` folder, then you use this to load the file:

```
$("#slider li#" + nextId).load("assets/case_study_content/file.txt #pickup");
```

Comment: I tried that but didn't work.Actually I think this is happening because of seo urls.

Comment: @user3671491: Then you may need to reevaluate what the URLs are. The only thing that matters is what URLs the browsers see, not where the files actually are on the server.

Comment: Sorted out. There was a htaccess file which was stopping the file to load.Thanks a lot for your help :)